# Using ALL in SQL query

Tags: sql

I have a table that has an identifier and an attribute, something like:

| Number | Status |
| --- | --- |
| 5555001 | Open |
| 5555001 | Closed |
| 5555002 | Open |
| 5555003 | Open |
| 5555003 | Open |
| 5555004 | Closed |

I want to write a SQL query that would pull back ID numbers that ONLY have every status as Open.  So the output should bring back 5555002 and 5555003.  It would not count 5555001 because one of the entries has a status of Closed.

The query I wrote was:

```
  FROM table t
  where t.status NOT IN (select t1.number
               from table t1
               where t1.status != 'Open')
```

While this brings back a count, I don't know that it's the right count.  Is there a better way to do this query using "ALL"?

Answer (score 0):

You can use aggregation:

```
select number
from t
group by number
having min(status) = max(status) and
       min(status) = 'Open';
```

If you have a separate table with one row per `number`, you could also use:

```
select n.*
from numbers n
where not exists (select 1
                  from t
                  where t.number = n.number and
                        t.status <> 'Open'
                 );
```

However, I can't think a natural way to write this using `ALL`.  I mean, you *could* write:

```
select n.*
from n
where 'Open' = all (select t.status from t where t.number = n.number);
```

That is actually an interesting approach to the problem.  It is just unusual to check that all values in a set (returned by the subquery) are all the same.